# How do I make my php code correctly output a JSON Array containing objects and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

At present my `JSON` looks like this:

```
[{
    "user_review_ids": {
        "category": "cat1",
        "name": "name1",
        "phone": "phone1",
        "comment": "com1",
        "reviewid": 32
    }
}, {
    "user_review_ids": {
        "category": "cat2",
        "name": "name2",
        "phone": "phone2",
        "comment": "com2",
        "reviewid": 76
    }
}], [{
    "private_review_ids": {
        "category": "cat1",
        "name": "name1",
        "phone": "phone1",
        "comment": "com1",
        "reviewid": 240
    }
}, {
    "private_review_ids": {
        "category": "cat2",
        "name": "name2",
        "phone": "phone2",
        "comment": "com2",
        "reviewid": 241
    }
}]
```

Which...is not correct `JSON`. `Jsonlint.com` will tell you that.

The way it should be is:

```
[{
    "user_review_ids": [{
        "category": "cat1",
        "name": "name1",
        "phone": "phone1",
        "comment": "com1",
        "reviewid": 32
    }, {
        "category": "cat2",
        "name": "name2",
        "phone": "phone2",
        "comment": "com2",
        "reviewid": 76
    }],
    "private_review_ids": [{
        "category": "cat1",
        "name": "name1",
        "phone": "phone1",
        "comment": "com1",
        "reviewid": 240
    }, {
        "category": "cat2",
        "name": "name2",
        "phone": "phone2",
        "comment": "com2",
        "reviewid": 241
    }]
}]
```

Can you tell me what I need to do with my `php` code so it outputs the correct `JSON`?

The code right now is:

```
<?php
    require('file.php');

    $UserReviewID = ('32,76');
    $UserReviewID = explode(",",$UserReviewID);

    $PrivateReviewID = ('240,241');
    $PrivateReviewID = explode(",",$PrivateReviewID);

    //for user_review_ids
    $results = array();

    //for private_review_ids
    $results2 = array();

    foreach($UserReviewID as $UserReviewID) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE review_id = ?";
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $stmt2->bind_param('i', $UserReviewID) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {//make an array called $results
            $results[] = array('user_review_ids' => array(
                'category' => $row['cat_name'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'phone' => $row['phone'],
                'comment' => $row['comment'],
                'reviewid' => $row['review_id'],
            ));
        }
    }

        foreach($PrivateReviewID as $PrivateReviewID) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE review_id = ?";
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $stmt2->bind_param('i', $PrivateReviewID) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {//make an array called $results2
            $results2[] = array('private_review_ids' => array(
                'category' => $row['cat_name'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'phone' => $row['phone'],
                'comment' => $row['comment'],
                'reviewid' => $row['review_id'],
            ));
        }
    }

        echo json_encode($results) .",";
        echo json_encode($results2);
?>
```

Comment: You cant json_encode twice, instead join the arrays and do it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenating the outputs of multiple json_encode operations does not produce valid JSON. You need to create a data structure such than you can run json_encode once and include everything in it.

Also, to get the structure you showed, you need to change how you create the arrays resulting from the database rows - you're creating multiple items with the same index.

This should work:

```
<?php
    require('file.php');

    $UserReviewID = ('32,76');
    $UserReviewID = explode(",",$UserReviewID);

    $PrivateReviewID = ('240,241');
    $PrivateReviewID = explode(",",$PrivateReviewID);

    //for user_review_ids
    $results = array();

    //for private_review_ids
    $results2 = array();

    foreach($UserReviewID as $UserReviewID) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE review_id = ?";
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $stmt2->bind_param('i', $UserReviewID) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {//make an array called $results
            $results[] = array(
                'category' => $row['cat_name'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'phone' => $row['phone'],
                'comment' => $row['comment'],
                'reviewid' => $row['review_id'],
            ));
        }
    }

        foreach($PrivateReviewID as $PrivateReviewID) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE review_id = ?";
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $stmt2->bind_param('i', $PrivateReviewID) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {//make an array called $results2
            $results2[] = array(
                'category' => $row['cat_name'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'phone' => $row['phone'],
                'comment' => $row['comment'],
                'reviewid' => $row['review_id'],
            ));
        }
    }

    $combinedResults = array(array('user_review_ids' => $results, 'private_review_ids' => $results2));
    echo json_encode($combinedResults);
?>
```

Having said that, I'm not convinced you actually need the very outer array in your sample result, it doesn't seem to serve much purpose since it only has one - fixed - item in it. If you wanted to ditch that, then the last- but-one line would be

```
    $combinedResults = array('user_review_ids' => $results, 'private_review_ids' => $results2);
```

instead, which will just return a single object with those field names.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to json_encode a single array. Perhaps something like:

```
echo json_encode( array_merge($results, $results2) );
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am getting the keys `user_review_ids` and `private_review_ids` repeated in each object whereas I just want them once, let me investigate...

Comment: @CHarris this is because you create those key sagain every time you output a row from the respective DB tables. See my answer for a solution which avoids that

Comment: I was wondering whether actually you should just be pushing the array to a variable rather than an array. I.e. `$results = array(...);` instead of `$results[] = array(...)`

Comment: @AndrewChart since that code is in a loop, that would simply overwrite one variable lots of times, and result in only the last row of data ever being returned from each table.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Looking too quickly by eye, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
 echo json_encode($results) .",";
 echo json_encode($results2);
```

use

```
echo json_encode(array_merge($results,$results2));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the inbuilt php function [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
example:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=127.0.0.1", "user", "password");
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
```

good luck !

Comment: OP is using mysqli

Comment: this is a generic example of no relevance or direct benefit to the question. It uses the wrong DB library and entirely misses the point that OP already knows about json_encode, but is having an issue with the specific format of the data being output